# Can't get this function to work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a hangman game using instructions from codecademy, but I'm having a hard time following alone. In the guessLetter function below, I've added two lines of code following the instructions they gave me

This

```
shown = alterAt(checkLetter,letter,shown);           ///this is mine
```

and this

```
checkLetter = indexOf(letter, checkLetter +1);
```

However, I can't get the tests to pass. I'd be grateful if you could assist.

```
// Skip to guessLetter(). You shouldn't need to touch this function.
function alterAt ( n, c, originalString ) {
    return originalString.substr(0,n) + c + originalString.substr(n+1,originalString.length);
}

function guessLetter( letter, shown, answer ) {
    var checkLetter = -1;  // This variable will hold the indexOf()

    checkLetter = answer.indexOf(letter); // Single Argument Version starting at 0
    while ( checkLetter >= 0 ) {

        // Replace the letter in shown with alterAt() and then store in shown.
       shown = alterAt(checkLetter,letter,shown);           ///this is mine
        // Use indexOf() again and store in checkLetter

        checkLetter = indexOf(letter, checkLetter +1);       ///this is mine
    }

    // Return our string, modified or not
    return shown;
}
```

**Update**

If the guess is correct, it's supposed to return shown modified by the guess. For example, if the word is tree and the player guesses 'e', it should return '__ee.' Here's a fiddle I can't get to work using the word 'whatever': http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/YAPWm/2/

Comment: Example html and expected result?

Comment: If the guess is correct, it's supposed to return shown modified by the guess. For example, if the word is tree and the player guesses 'e', it should return '__ee.' Here's a fiddle I can't get to work using the word 'whatever' http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/YAPWm/

Comment: Not _the_ problem, but you are using [`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) incorrectly: the second parameter should be the length, not the end index - you are using it like [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) - so your second `.substr()` op is trying to extract characters past the end of the string, though this doesn't actually cause an error. Your second use could be `originalString.substr(n+1)` - without second param it selects to end of string.

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry, posted the wrong fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/YAPWm/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error on this line:

```
checkLetter = indexOf(letter, checkLetter +1);
```

The `.indexOf()` method needs to be called on a string like it was on the line before the `while()`. Change it to this:

```
checkLetter = answer.indexOf(letter, checkLetter +1);
```

Working version: http://jsfiddle.net/YAPWm/1/